# what's the fastest way to read a file line by line?

Tags: perl

What is the fastest way to read a file line by line in perl?

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'fit.log') or die; 

1. while(<$fh>){
blah, blah, blah
}


2. while(defined(my $line = <$filehandle>)){
blah, blah, blah
}

is #2 the same as #1?????

3. Tie::File

4. Any others?
```

Comment: why do you want to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as speed, the actual file i/o will almost certainly swamp any differences in how you write the surrounding loop.  But benchmarking or profiling will give you the real answers.